# How to debug Tornado coroutine (asyncio)

Tags: python, python-asyncio, pdb, ipdb

I'm trying to debug a Tornado coroutine that, under the hood, uses an asyncio implementation.

As debugger I'm using `ipdb`, so in my code I've inserted `import ipdb; ipdb.setTrace()`

The code is:

```
@coroutine
def get(self, user_id, _user):
    user = yield self.create_user(user_id)
    import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace();
    ...
```

The problem is that the debugger, instead of enter in debug mode returns

```
 File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 425, in run_forever
    raise RuntimeError('This event loop is already running')
```

Any idea how to fix it? Do you use another approach to debug asyncio process?

The code is executed as `python main.py`

Comment: I think IPython will try to run it's own event loop, since you're already running one that might be a problem.